# How can I get an XCUITest application (the XCUI Test application, not the SUT) to access the photos library?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I'd like to be able to have my XCUITest application post an image to a server. I've installed the image using the `xcrun simctl addmedia` command, but I can't figure out to how to access it from the XCUITest class.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using UITest to access the default photos installed in the simulator Photos library, and then using the SUT to post to the server in question.

Answer (score 0):

The recorder doesn't work inside UIRemoteViews like the photos library. What you can do is setup a ui test and get it to the point where the photos library is open then set a breakpoint and view/print the view hierarchy. That is how I figured out how to select one of the default photos in the iPhone simulator.

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    //Get to the camera or library prompt
    app.sheets.buttons["Choose From Library"].tap()
    app.cells["Camera Roll"].tap()
    app.cells["Photo, Landscape, March 12, 2011, 7:17 PM"].tap()
```

Comment: Probably need to wait for the CameraRoll and other items accessed by the [] to appear.